# PHP - similar_text() function returns inaccurate results?

Tags: php, function, text

I'm working on a searchengine, and to filter out all the bad results i compare the result string with the search query, and if the results exceeds 30% it's returned.

I know that works, i've done it before and it's great. However, for some odd reason it appears to return some really weird results for me now. I've been playing around with it for a while now and i just can't figure it out!

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
 $tmp_procent = similar_text("banana", "banana");
 //if ($tmp_procent > 30) {
  $result[] = array('id' => $id,
        'category_id' => $category_id,
        'example' => html($example),
        'example_name' => html($example_name));
 //}
 $procent_arr[] = $tmp_procent;
}
return $procent_arr;
```

As you can see i've commented the IF statement out, so right now it returns all results. But that's not really the point... As you can see, i'm comparing two exactly identical strings (banana), and then returning them.

This is what i get after printing out the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 5
)
```

Eh, what? That's not correct! Shouldn't it be 100 on all results?

Any ideas guys?

Thanks!

Oh and i spelled "procent" in Swedish, so it's not misspelled, in case you noticed that. The reason it returns 3 results is because it finds three matches in the database.

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php, the function is supposed to yield the number of matching characters in both strings and return the percentage in the third parameter by reference. Then however, I'd still expect your result to be an array with `6` instead of `5`.

Comment: Oh, god. I don't know why it returned 5 instead of 6, but the reason it didn't work as expected was because i forgot to add the last param. It works like a charm now (almost, i've got some other issues, but i'll figure those out myself). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you were trying to do.

I wonder why it returned 5. 'banana' has 6 characters. I think you did some typo?

Refer to [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php), the syntax is similar_text($str1, $str2, &$perc)
Adding the last parameter does not affect on return value. The return value would be 6 for 'banana'.
What the $perc is, it a reference to the result of formula in the core of the function

```
(similar_characters/average of characters*100)
```

This is what has the value of 100 in your case.

```
$procent_arr = []; // Good practice to define your array out of the loop
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $tmp_procent = similar_text('banana', 'banana', $procent);
    if ($tmp_procent > 30) {
        $result[] = [
            'id' => $id,
            'category_id' => $category_id,
            'example' => html($example),
            'example_name' => html($example_name)
        ];
    }
    $procent_arr [] = $procent;
}
return $procent_arr;
```

The return value would be:

```
[0]=>100
[1]=>100
[2]=>100
```